# How to query profiler instrumented IL code address using Windbg and SOS extension?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, sos, clr-profiling-api

I have been debugging a .Net framework (4.8) CLR profiler codebase using Windbg and extension SOS.

I am starting the target application debug binary through windbg and after the instrumentation has happened for a function (within assembly mscorlib) I use the DumpIL command with the target function's MethodDesc address which gives me the IL opcode listing and the IL address but this is same as the address(RVA) and the IL opcodes which was present in the original assembly as seen through ILDASM.

I found out that this is a known issue and was fixed in the .Netcore SOS extension. Refer [Github Issue link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/8520)

I have tried out another tool dnSpy but see the same issue here as well.

Are there any .Net framework specific debugging tools which can provide the address of the profiler modified IL code or the function IL opcode listing?

Comment: Measuring performance in the debug build?

Comment: @ThomasWeller - Not interested in performance of the target app. Debugging to understand the profiler code base.